# SalesOrderStorage::DoAdd This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks. HRESULT=0x80040527

Tags: quickbooks

QB 2013 pro
Write it once - Shopping Cart Assistent

Everything was working fine till today, I started getting the above error when I would attempt to capture the orders.  There may have been a QB update between the last time it worked and now (How would I check?)

Here is the output of qbsdklog.txt

```
20130611.161018 I   5012    RequestProcessor    ========= Started Connection =========
20130611.161018 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v12.0
20130611.161018 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Connection opened by app named 'Shopping Cart Assistant'
20130611.161018 D   5012    CRLInstaller    CRL path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2013\Components\Services\
20130611.161018 D   5012    CRLInstaller    No new CRL files found.
20130611.161018 I   5012    CertVerifier    The file does not contain an Authenticode signature.
20130611.161019 D   5012    CRLInstaller    CRL path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2013\Components\Services\
20130611.161019 D   5012    CRLInstaller    No new CRL files found.
20130611.161019 D   5012    CertVerifier    The embedded module does not contain an Authenticode signature.
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Begin Session started...
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Current Process is elevated
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Current User is in AdminGroup
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Current Process is ran as Admin
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Current Process Integrity Level : 3000
20130611.161019 V   5012    RequestProcessor    Not in-proc request.
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    File info: "G:\BSN\QuickBooks\quickbooks\Blue Sage Naturals, LLC6-11-13.qbw", v23.0R7 (2305), pro, standard_stratum
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Getting an instance of pRunningInfo
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Getting an instance of pRunningInfo using pRunningInstanceFinder 
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    QuickBooks is not running..
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Starting QuickBooks (launch): Install info: v23.0R7 (2305), pro, standard_stratum
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Performing QB Launch Retries
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Check QB process ID before calling instance finder to find it.
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    QuickBooks is not running.!
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Quickbooks is not running currently
20130611.161019 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Launch a new instance of Quickbooks
20130611.161022 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Getting the IUnknown COM instance of QB
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Obtained the IUnknown COM instance of QB without an exception
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    QuickBooks launch succeeded.
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    get_CompanyFileIsOpen call successful
20130611.161022 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Opening the file in the DoNotCare mode.
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Attempt getting the Request Processor interface
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc2
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc3
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc4
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc5
20130611.161022 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Calling raw_SDKOpenFile4
20130611.161027 V   6600    EventCapturer   initializing company file path.
20130611.161027 D   6600    EventSub:Load   No subscriptions found in data file.
20130611.161027 D   6600    EventSub:Synch  No sub config file. Removing 0 event subscriptions.
20130611.161027 D   6600    COMEventHandler Create IQBEventCallback
20130611.161027 D   6600    COMEventHandler Error creating callback for ProSeries
20130611.161027 D   6600    COMEventHandler    Error Message: class not registered
20130611.161028 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Successfully opened the data file: G:\BSN\QuickBooks\quickbooks\Blue Sage Naturals, LLC6-11-13.qbw
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    COM access to QuickBooks starting ...
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'Shopping Cart Assistant' starting requests (process 5012).

20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Begin dumping request data received from client
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest <?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="3.0" ?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><CustomerAddRq requestID = "1"><CustomerAdd><Name>Name Fake</Name><IsActive>1</IsActive><CompanyName></CompanyName><FirstName>Fake</FirstName><LastName>Name</LastName><BillAddress><Addr1>Fake Name</Addr1><Addr2>123 N Anywhere Rd</Addr2><Addr3></Addr3><City>Nowhere</City><State>CO</State><PostalCode>81321</PostalCode></BillAddress><ShipAddress><Addr1>Fake Name</Addr1><Addr2>123 N Anywhere Rd</Addr2><Addr3></Addr3><City>Nowhere</City><State>CO</State><PostalCode>81321</PostalCode></ShipAddress><Phone>(111) 111-1111</Phone><Email>noemail@yahoo.com</Email><Contact>Fake Name</Contact><SalesTaxCodeRef><FullName>Non</FullName></SalesTaxCodeRef><ItemSalesTaxRef><FullName>Out of state</FullName></ItemSalesTaxRef></CustomerAdd></CustomerAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest End dumping of request data received from client
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================

20130611.161029 D   6600    MacroManager::DumpMacroMap  Map contains no entries
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXParseManager   Using Xerces-c parser, version 2_5_0
20130611.161029 V   6600    XMLDtdMapper    TransformProcessingInstruction using DOCTYPE: <!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 3.0//EN' 'http://developer.intuit.com'>

20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving public ID: -//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 3.0//EN
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver qbxmlops30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlops30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving Public Entity took 0.0080 seconds
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxml30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxml30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0060 seconds
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxmlso30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlso30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    QBXMLMsgs   CustomerAddRq
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: CompanyName
20130611.161029 W   6600    QBNCustomerAdd::HandleAggregate unexpected tag 'CompanyName'.
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'CompanyName', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: Addr3
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'Addr3', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: Addr3
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'Addr3', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 I   6600    SpecVersion Current version of qbXML in use: 3.0
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Parsing took 0.0650 seconds
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  ADD: Customer Job
20130611.161029 E   6600    CustomerStorage::DoAdd  The name is already in use: Name Fake.
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 1 failed.
20130611.161029 D   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  There was 1 request processed.
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Executing Requests took 0.014 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Creating Response took 0.000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Response is 422 characters long
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Writing Response took 0.000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MacroManager::DumpMacroMap  Map contains no entries
20130611.161029 I   6600    MsgSetHandler   Finished.
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'Shopping Cart Assistant' finishing requests (process 5012), ret = 0.
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Finished processing requests, no errors.
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Processing requests took 0.092 seconds.
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    COM access to QuickBooks starting ...
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'Shopping Cart Assistant' starting requests (process 5012).

20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Begin dumping request data received from client
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest <?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="3.0" ?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><SalesOrderAddRq requestID = "2"><SalesOrderAdd><CustomerRef><FullName>Name Fake</FullName></CustomerRef><TemplateRef><FullName>BSN Sales Receipt-New</FullName></TemplateRef><TxnDate>2013-06-06</TxnDate><BillAddress><Addr1>Fake Name</Addr1><Addr2>123 N Anywhere Rd</Addr2><Addr3></Addr3><City>Nowhere</City><State>CO</State><PostalCode>81321</PostalCode></BillAddress><ShipAddress><Addr1>Fake Name</Addr1><Addr2>123 N Anywhere Rd</Addr2><Addr3></Addr3><City>Nowhere</City><State>CO</State><PostalCode>81321</PostalCode></ShipAddress><PONumber></PONumber><ItemSalesTaxRef><FullName>Out of state</FullName></ItemSalesTaxRef><IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted><SalesOrderLineAdd><ItemRef><FullName>ht8</FullName></ItemRef><Desc>SBT Hair Therapy 8 oz</Desc><Quantity>1</Quantity><Amount>28.00</Amount></SalesOrderLineAdd><SalesOrderLineAdd><ItemRef><FullName>sham</FullName></ItemRef><Desc>SBT Shampoo </Desc><Quantity>2</Quantity><Amount>56.00</Amount></SalesOrderLineAdd><SalesOrderLineAdd><ItemRef><FullName>Shipping</FullName></ItemRef><Desc>2</Desc><Amount>21.00</Amount></SalesOrderLineAdd></SalesOrderAdd></SalesOrderAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest End dumping of request data received from client
20130611.161029 V   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================

20130611.161029 D   6600    MacroManager::DumpMacroMap  Map contains no entries
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXParseManager   Using Xerces-c parser, version 2_5_0
20130611.161029 V   6600    XMLDtdMapper    TransformProcessingInstruction using DOCTYPE: <!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 3.0//EN' 'http://developer.intuit.com'>

20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving public ID: -//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 3.0//EN
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver qbxmlops30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlops30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving Public Entity took 0.0070 seconds
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxml30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxml30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0060 seconds
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxmlso30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlso30.dtd
20130611.161029 V   6600    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    QBXMLMsgs   SalesOrderAddRq
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: Addr3
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'Addr3', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: Addr3
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'Addr3', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 V   6600    SAXParseMediator    EndElement: empty aggregate: name and currentTag are the same: PONumber
20130611.161029 W   6600    QBNSalesOrderAdd::HandleAggregate   unexpected tag 'PONumber'.
20130611.161029 D   6600    SAXParseMediator    DispatchData:  'PONumber', no data to dispatch, dispatching empty string
20130611.161029 I   6600    SpecVersion Current version of qbXML in use: 3.0
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Parsing took 0.0540 seconds
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  ADD: Sales Order
20130611.161029 E   6600    SalesOrderStorage::DoAdd    This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks. HRESULT=0x80040527
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 2 failed.
20130611.161029 D   6600    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  There was 1 request processed.
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Executing Requests took 0.007 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Creating Response took 0.000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Response is 441 characters long
20130611.161029 D   6600    MsgSetHandler   Writing Response took 0.000 seconds
20130611.161029 D   6600    MacroManager::DumpMacroMap  Map contains no entries
20130611.161029 I   6600    MsgSetHandler   Finished.
20130611.161029 I   6600    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'Shopping Cart Assistant' finishing requests (process 5012), ret = 0.
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Finished processing requests, no errors.
20130611.161029 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Processing requests took 0.073 seconds.
20130611.161030 D   5012    RequestProcessor    During this session processed 2 requests.
20130611.161032 D   5012    RequestProcessor    Detaching SDK client from QB
20130611.161032 D   5012    RequestProcessor    End Session finished OK.
20130611.161032 I   5012    RequestProcessor    Connection closed by app named 'Shopping Cart Assistant'
20130611.161032 I   5012    RequestProcessor    ========== Ended Connection ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this was working previously with this version of QuickBooks?

It looks like you are using QuickBooks Pro, as indicated by the log:

```
20130611.161019 D   5012    RequestProcessor    File info: "G:\BSN\QuickBooks\quickbooks\Blue Sage Naturals, LLC6-11-13.qbw", v23.0R7 (2305), **pro**, standard_stratum
```

(notice the "pro" designation)

QuickBooks Pro does not support Sales Orders. Thus, you can't add a Sales Order to QuickBooks Pro via the API.

You'll have to upgrade to at least QuickBooks Premier.